# Override/Implement Members in MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, refactoring, monodevelop

I am working through the pluralsight videos on MonoTouch.  At one point, the trainer right clicks on the name of a derived class, and in the 'refactor' menu there is a function to override/implement members of that class.  When I click however (latest version), I see only 'rename.'

The person in this link had the same issue some time ago and has included screenshots - but noone replied to them in the MonoTouch discussion group:

http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Right-Click-Class-name-gt-Refactor-gt-Override-Implement-members-tt4655504.html#none

Has anyone experienced (and resolved!) this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the refactoring features were reorganized or removed (for now) in the rewrite of the code code completion engine that took place for MD 3.0.

You can still access this particular feature two ways:

1) After typing the "override" keyword, MD offers the members you can override/implement. Selecting one will cause it to be stubbed out.

2) You can override many members at once using the "Edit->Show Code Generation Window" command in the class body. This command doesn't have a keybinding on Mac by default, but you can assign one in Preferences.

Comment: Many thanks!  I had noticed the member list appearing, but it definitely isn't as nice as the previous function.  I hope it comes back!  Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop 3.0 (and later) removed some features (including a few about refactoring) since they were not as stable, fully functional (complete) or buggy.

The same features (or similar ones) are likely to come back in future releases.