# Missing Refactoring Options in MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm on version 3.0.3.5 of MonoDevelop and was looking at the Pluralsight tutorials for MonoTouch where John Sonmez uses a few refactoring Tools/methods in the ViewController that isn't available in my version of MonoDevelop. For example - Refactor->Override/Implement members... , Encapsulate fields... and a few more. The only Refactoring tool I have available in my popup-window is Rename :)

Is there an additional download available with more refactoring tools?

Thanks for any help, I'm still new to MonoDevelop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Sebastien, in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032880/override-implement-members-in-monodevelop)

> Some of the refactoring features were reorganized or removed (for now)
>   in the rewrite of the code code completion engine that took place for
>   MD 3.0.